# Errorcode CS1955 at every form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I add a new Form to my C# Project it always throws the error

> CS1955 "Non-invocable member 'name' cannot be used like a method.".

Even If i create a new Form and add it like

```
Application.Run(Form1());
```

in the Program.cs file in VS15 Enterprise

It still throws this error, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Visual Studio *really* tries to help you. Read the message carefully, and either click the link in the error list, or just simply [look it up](https://www.bing.com/search?q=compiler%20error%20cs1955&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=compiler%20error%20cs1955&sc=0-7&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=9468227B0F624436BBAE00C4026C4411)

Comment: Form1 is a type, not a method.  Create an instance of the type instead, `new Form1()`

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved